# Region of attraction and stability via Liapunov's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, basins-of-attraction

**EXERCISE:**

> Estimate the region of stability for the stationary point $O(0,0)$ given the differential system:
>   $$x'=y$$
>   $$y'=x^7-2\cdot x-y$$
>   using the liapunov's funcion $V(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot(x+y)^2$

**Attempt**:
We have that $V'=V_x \cdot x'+V_y \cdot y'$

So,$V'=(2x+y) \cdot y +(x+y)\cdot (x^7-2x -y)=x^8-2x^2+x^7y-xy $

So,how can i find the sign of V'.I think that i have to find it $V'<0$ everywhere outside the origin and the stationary point $O(0,0)$ will be asymptotic stable!

After,that how can i find the region of attraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very small $x$ you can, for a first picture, ignore the higher degree terms and just consider the quadratic terms. As
$$
-2x^2-xy=-\frac18(4x+y)^2 +\frac18y^2
$$
you see that on the line $y=-4x$ the whole expression is
$$
2x^2-3x^8
$$
which is positive for $x^6<\frac23$. Thus your Lyapunov function does not generate level sets where the solutions always flow downwards.

---

In contrast $V=\frac12y^2+x^2-\frac18x^8$ leads to $\dot V=-y^2$.

Comment: Τhe problem is that i have to use this ill-adapted liapunov's function!

Comment: @ParisK.Patsogiannis: Well, this answer clearly shows that you can't, so either you've misread the problem, or whoever gave it to you messed up.

Comment: @HansLundmark i re-read the problem again but it's not my fault.Maybe,the author didn't check his own exercise!